# Swift: Receiving memory warning followed by crash

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm receiving a memory warning followed by crash after some minutes loading up my application (**Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue**)

I've read some answers on the internet and I think it might be happening because I'm storing my sprite animations in an dictionary array, like this:

```
class CharacterCreate {

    var player = SKSpriteNode()
    var playerAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
    var playerAnimation = [String : [SKTexture]]()
    let playerAnimationTypes = ["run", "static", "jump", "armed_static", "armed_run", "armed_jump"] // Player's animations
    var playerAnimationsArray = [String]() // Array with all player Sprites
    let playerAnimationSpritesPrefix = "Player_"
    let runAnimationTime = 0.1
    init(initPosition: CGPoint) {

        playerAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Player_anim")

        for i in 0 ..< playerAtlas.textureNames.count {
            playerAnimationsArray.append(playerAtlas.textureNames[i]) // Gets all the animations image names
        }

        for i in 0 ..< playerAnimationTypes.count {

            let animations = playerAnimationsArray.filter{$0.hasPrefix(playerAnimationSpritesPrefix + playerAnimationTypes[i])}.sort() // Gets all image names for a specific type of animation (eg: Player_run0.png, Player_run1.png, etc)

            for j in 0 ..< animations.count {

                if playerAnimation[playerAnimationTypes[i]] == nil {
                    playerAnimation[playerAnimationTypes[i]] = [] // Creates array if doesn't exist
                }

                playerAnimation[playerAnimationTypes[i]]!.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: animations[j])) // Add texture to make the animation

            }

        }
```

I don't know if the problem happens because of the way that I'm storing the animations or if it's happening because of other thing, but it always happen like 15 minutes after opening the app. If you guys need any other information I'd be glad to provide it

@edit: I also don't know if the problem happens because of this, but I have some values constantly changing at the update function and, since it is called at each frame, I think it also might overload the memory used, I don't know

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    if (Player.playerOldY != Player.player.position.y && !Player.playerOnGround) {
        Player.playerOnAir = true
        if (Player.playerRunningJumpAnimation == false) {
            Player.playerRunningJumpAnimation = true
            spriteAnimation(Player.player, action: Player.playerAnimation["jump"]!, time: Player.runAnimationTime)
        }
    }

    Player.playerOldY = Player.player.position.y
    Player.playerOldX = Player.player.position.x

    if pressedButtons.indexOf(directionButtons["left"]!) != nil {
        Player.player.position.x -= Player.playerWalkingSpeed
        Player.playerDirection = (pressedButtons.count > 1 ? Player.playerDirection : -1)
        Player.player.xScale = Player.playerScale * Player.playerDirection
    }
    if pressedButtons.indexOf(directionButtons["right"]!) != nil {
        Player.player.position.x += Player.playerWalkingSpeed
        Player.playerDirection = (pressedButtons.count > 1 ? Player.playerDirection : 1)
        Player.player.xScale = Player.playerScale * Player.playerDirection
    }

}
```

@edit2: So, I found out that, if I remove the ground AND the player, the memory stops to grow. But if I add just one of the back, the memory starts to grow constantly again

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    // Ground Create
    ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "grassSprite")
    ground.setScale(3)
    ground.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: 100 + ground.frame.height)

    // Ground Physics
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: ground.size)
    ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ground
    ground.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    ground.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    ground.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    ground.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    self.addChild(ground)


    self.addChild(Player.player)
```

Comment: I doubt it has something to do with the posted code... There is something in the logic of the program that happens very late, so `init` is not responsible with a memory problem. Try to use Instruments to observe what happens dynamically... Don't you create too many characters?

Comment: I don't think that creating many characters is the problem too... Even when the player is static I receive the memory warning

Comment: Do you mean that doing nothing for 15mn produces an error? Did you activated show node count on the SKView to be sure?

Comment: I did... Showing node count uses that amount of memory? I'm running the instruments tool here and it seems that the memory used by the game keeps growing constantly

Comment: Try to trace where does this memory come from... You are constantly allocating memory somewhere. What are you doing in spriteAnimation? Strange to launch this on every frame...

Comment: it checks if the player is falling and if the falling animation is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot of debugging and discovered that if I took out the physics of all objects, the memory leak disappeared. So it seems that the problem was with the game physics, which is something very odd.

Then I did a lot of research and discovered that showing the game physics takes a lot of memory. So, I just had to take off the line `skView.showsPhysics = true` from GameViewController and the problem was solved.